# Is there a way to subscribe to Course Changes (Archive/Deletion) in Google Classroom PubSub Registrations?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-pubsub, google-classroom

I have a working Google Classroom Pub Sub Registration Service.

There is a sequential registration process for each course in the organization, however this only emits when there are course work changes.

Is there a way to tap into courses being **Archived** or **Deleted**?
I would like to run a background function to update our system by removing courses that are either archived or deleted by any teacher or admin.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Rafael i looked in documentation and found that you can list `archived` and `suspended` courses by using [CourseState](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses#CourseState) parameter.

Then you can use the `courses.list` method to achieve what you're looking for.

```
GET https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses
```

Its very well documented and you can even execute the methods using this [link](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list?apix_params=%7B%22courseStates%22%3A%5B%22ARCHIVED%22%5D%7D)

Comment: Hi Pedro, this does not answer my question. I am aware of the ability to retrieve courses with specific states. I am looking to get push notifications from the [Registrations](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/registrations). My ideal experience is to receive a pub-sub notification stating that a course was archived, then remove that course from our db on the spot. I am already removing archived courses with a manual sync but would like to circumvent that process

Comment: Oh i see... maybe a good workaround is to create a forEach function to compare the courses list from your db and the courses from the api... and you can trigger this function everytime you get a sub notification

Comment: We already compare all the courses when we need to sync everything. Running a check for courses when we receive any arbitrary notifications (eg. for course work completion or rostering) doesn't seem like a great solution. I am looking to award the bounty for native solutions, not work arounds.

Comment: I know Rafael i'm no trying to award the bounty, i was just trying to figure out a solution due to an API limitation.